# Hilt Field Injection throwing "property not initialized" error?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I just followed the official Hilt docs and tried to implement a simple field injection, here is the MainActivity:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import dagger.hilt.EntryPoint
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint
import javax.inject.Inject

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    //field Injection
    @Inject lateinit var analytics: AnalyticsAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        println(analytics.doAThing())
    }
}

class AnalyticsAdapter @Inject constructor() {
    fun doAThing(): String{
        return "Hello"
    }
}
```

I also have a Application class which is declared in my manifest:

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class MyApplication: Application() {

}
```

Here is the error it throws:

```
2021-07-23 01:24:11.686 32325-32325/com.example.hilt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hilt, PID: 32325
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hilt/com.example.hilt.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property analytics has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property analytics has not been initialized
        at com.example.hilt.MainActivity.getAnalytics(MainActivity.kt:13)
        at com.example.hilt.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Using version 2.38 of Hilt.

Why are the simplest things not working -.-

Comment: This may happen if you miss `@AndroidEntryPoint`. Try to stop gradle daemon and rebuild your project. Your code is work fine for me.

Comment: Try `Build -> Clean Project` and then `Build -> Rebuild Project`, your code looks good. What's your Android Studio version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two hours I figured out that your project build.gradle file should have a lower version of hilt in the classpath line:

Downgrade from version 2.38 to 2.28-alpha:

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:2.28-alpha'
```

Then in the app build.gradle file keep using version 2.38:

```
implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.38"
kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.38"
```

after downgrading from 2.38 to 2.28-alpha in the app build.gradle file you have to clear the cache of the app on your device otherwise it will still crash.

Welcome to Android Native Development, a fun experience for the whole family